# Export to Excel in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

we want to download excel file using *excel 3.1* maatwebsite.
it can help me to download file but when we increase data through sql file 
we are getting such type of error given below:-

> Gateway Timeout The gateway did not receive a timely response from the
>   upstream server or application.

Also we increased the memory limit in php.ini file to 512 mb and execution time to 300s.

```
   $records=DB::select('SELECT p.EWSCustID,p.PLAppId,CONCAT(FirstName," ", LastName) AS FULLNAME,p.LoanAmount,e.EmpStatus,csp.EmployerName,p.Designation,p.NetSalary,City,EmailID,MobileNo,State,DateOfBirth,Pincode,ci.PanNo,
         p.AppliedBank,p.AppliedDate,p.UTMCampaign,p.UTMMedium,p.UTMSource,p.UTMTerm,p.UTMContent 
         From personal_loans p, customer_profiles cp,customer_secondary_profile csp,customer_identification ci,employeestatuses e  
         WHERE p.EWSCustID=cp.EWSCustID AND p.EWSCustID=csp.EWSCustID AND p.EWSCustID = ci.EWSCustID AND p.EmployerStatus=e.EmpStatusId AND  
          DATE(p.AppliedDate) BETWEEN ? AND ?',[$StartDate,$EndDate]);
```

we getting proper data from this query when we increased the data limit then it get occurred error otherwise it able to download the excel file.

For exporting the file to excel we are using this code given below

```
Excel::download(new UsersExport($Product),$FileName);

here $filename is $FileName="Bank Response.xlsx";
and $Product = "personal_loan";
```

I expect the excel file will download 60k rows.

Comment: Question is not clear which Excel library are you using here?

Comment: Do you get the error before the 300s has passed?

Comment: Excel 3.1 package by maatwebsite this is library which she is using @RaymondNijland

Comment: @BramVerstraten yes we are getting before 300s

Comment: Can you try to just get the result from `new UsersExport($Product)` without creating the Excel file? Do you still get the same error?